# How to format a double with more digits?

Tags: c#, double, number-formatting

I have a double value and I want to convert it to a string with more than the default 15 digits. How can I accomplish this?

```
(1.23456789987654321d).ToString(); // 1.23456789987654
(12.3456789987654321d).ToString(); // 12.3456789987654
(1.23456789987654321d).ToString("0.######################################"); // 1.23456789987654
(1.23456789987654321d).ToString("0.0000000000000000000000000000000"); // 1.2345678998765400000000000000000
```

Comment: The `Regex \d+.\d+` could do it. But a `Decimal` would be better.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/611564/453277)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Converting 20 digit precision double to string and back again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611552/c-sharp-converting-20-digit-precision-double-to-string-and-back-again)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a double value and I want to convert it to a string with more than the default 15 digits.

Why? It's basically going to be garbage after 15 digits. You can get the *exact* value using my [`DoubleConverter`](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) class:

```
string exact = DoubleConverter.ToExactString(value);
```

... but after 15 digits, the rest is just noise.

If you want more than 15 significant digits of *meaningful* data, use `decimal`.

Comment: How does your DoubleConverter class's behavior differ from ToString("R")?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion: "R" only has to give enough information to get back to the original value uniquely (roundtrip). My code gives the *exact* value of the double.

Comment: It actually is not noise, especially if you are verifying that you can parse the before/after values *EXACTLY*.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with double as it does not support a precision of more than 15 digits.
You can try using decimal data type:

```
using System;

namespace Code.Without.IDE
{
    public class FloatingTypes
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal deci = 1.23456789987654321M;
            decimal decix = 1.23456789987654321987654321987654321M;
            double doub = 1.23456789987654321d;
            Console.WriteLine(deci); // prints - 1.23456789987654321
            Console.WriteLine(decix); // prints - 1.2345678998765432198765432199
            Console.WriteLine(doub); // prints - 1.23456789987654
        }
    }
}
```