# Model binder can't handle double.MAX string representation back to double

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, type-conversion, double, modelbinder

Right now I have a ViewModel with a property `double Maximum`. On the view side it's kept in a hidden input to help with unobtrusive validation.

When post backing the values, the binding silently fails. I had to put a breakpoint on this line:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
```

and check which `ModelState` property had an error. Then I found that this `double Maximum` property had an error with the following message:

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Double' failed. See the inner exception for more
>   information.

On the view side inspecting the `HTML` with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) I can see that the hidden input has this value:

```
1.79769313486232E+308
```

which correctly represents [double.MAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue.aspx) constant.

I found this Scott Hanselman post from *Jan/2005* (almost 9 years ago) which deals with something similar:

[Why you can't Double.Parse(Double.MaxValue.ToString()) or System.OverloadExceptions when using Double.Parse](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyYouCantDoubleParseDoubleMaxValueToStringOrSystemOverloadExceptionsWhenUsingDoubleParse.aspx)

Is there something wrong with my app config or this direct conversion from `string` back to `double` is not supported? I *think* it should handle it without errors.

Note: I tried changing the hidden input value with Firebug and did as Scott mentions on his post: I subtracted 1 from the last digit...

```
1.79769313486231E+308
```

and did a postback again just to find the model binder handled it correctly this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `@Html.HiddenFor` to create the hidden input.

After carefully reading Scott's post I saw that he mentions the *round-trip* specifier. I also found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611564/114029) here on StackOverflow.

> The R stands for "round-trip". From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx?ppud=4):
>
> This format is supported only for the Single and Double types. The round-trip specifier guarantees that a numeric value converted to a
>   string will be parsed back into the same numeric value.

So I did this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Maximum,
                new { Value = Model.Maximum.ToString("R") })
```

Now this gives me a `double.MAX` string representation that can be round-tripped back to a `double` on the controller side:

```
1.7976931348623157E+308
```

Nice... problem solved.

Hope it helps anyone that might face this same problem in the future.

---

How interesting this is?!

```
1.79769313486232E+308   // double.MAX
1.7976931348623157E+308 // double.MAX.ToString("R")
```

It's worth mentioning that all this is also applicable to `double.MIN`.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Still the binding silently fails. My code is `@Html.HiddenFor(i => i.id, new { Value = Double.MaxValue.ToString("R") });`

Comment: WOW... you're having the same problem right now... I just posted the question 1 hour ago. Are you sure your backing `id` property is of type `double`? Also make sure that the model binding is failing for this `id` property. Maybe you have more properties and one of those other properties is the culprit.

Comment: Yes. Id is the only property in View Model. My Code : `return PartialView(new PartialViewModel2() { id = double.MaxValue });`

Comment: Can you inspect the hidden input on the HTML and see if its value match this? `1.7976931348623157E+308`

Comment: The rendered HTML tag: `<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" data-val-number="The field id must be a number." data-val="true" value="1.7976931348623157E+308">`

Comment: Well... it's set to the correct round-trip value. Now what I'd do is: put a breakpoint in `if(ModelState.IsValid)` in your controller action method that's receiving this Model\ViewModel and see what's the offending property. If it is the `id` one, then something is wrong with your code or even this value is not present in the postback values that are going to the server.

Comment: This is not moving to my `Post` *Action Method* Because Validation is imposed for `Hidden` Field.

Comment: Ah OK... that's the problem. If you're using `jQuery.Validate` latest bits it should not impose validation for hidden inputs. By default it ignores hidden inputs.

Comment: :). Back to your own original query. My data is valid. Why is Client stopping to post the Data to my Post Action Method ?

Comment: This is going to be difficult to answer because I can't see you complete ViewModel, view code, etc... if you want a definitive answer you'd better ask a question here at StackOverflow and specify how you're handling validation. Feel free to paste the link to your question here (if you happen to post one) so that I can further analyze your case.