# C# Parse String To Double Without Scientific Notation

Tags: c#, string, parsing, double, notation

I want to parse "7.7E-07" string into double so it looks like: "0.00000077" But none of the methods that I've found  on the internet work. This is my code:

```
double someNumber = double.Parse("7.7E-07", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

and it still produce '7.7E-07'

Comment: And you not re-convert it to another string like `someNumber.ToString("R")`? (similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611552/c-sharp-converting-20-digit-precision-double-to-string-and-back-again)

Comment: When you debug your code, and look at the content of `someNumber` it is shown as `7.7E-07`? Hard to believe

Comment: Your issue isn't with the parsing of the string, but in fact the opposite: going from `double` to `string`. See linked duplicate

Comment: You first have to parse as double, then use ToString() to change to your output.  double someNumber = double.Parse("7.7E-07");  someNumber.ToString("0:0.00000000")