# C# GridViewColumn with Double member assign string value

Tags: c#, string, double

I have a GridViewColumn with double as its member. Instead of assign double value I would like to assign string values to it. Is it possible to assign a string value to a double ?

e.g.

```
Double Value = 3.45 instead of 3.45
```

I want to display -Ur-

Comment: Why don't you use a `DataGrdiViewTextBoxColumn`?  You can populate it with double data type via ToString()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it was legacy code using GridViewColumn, let me try using the DataGrdiViewTextBoxColumn.

Comment: I am getting an error DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  is not supported in a windows Presentation Foundation Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert just about any value type to a string type by simply calling .ToString() on it:

```
double number = 3.45;
number.ToString();
```

Here is another answer that explains options for parameters of .ToString() as well:

[Another Answer with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611564/6448599)

Comment: Since my GridViewColumn is double when I use ToString("-Ur-") it displays as 0 only.

Comment: Could you post the code of your .aspx file (and code behind file)?

Comment: <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />     <----- in xml                                                                               public Double Value { get; private set; } <--- cs file . I want to display string instead for Value instead of Double. Is there any way to display string instead of changing the data type to String ?